# How to convert line segment into curve?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have been watching a Lynda.com course on Illustrator CC 2015 by Justin Seeley, https://www.lynda.com/Illustrator-tutorials/Illustrator-CC-Essential-Training-2015/370378-2.html  In Chapter 5 > "Modifying existing shapes and paths", he discusses using the Pen Tool to bend lines.

Basically, he draws a shape (say a rectangle), chooses the Pen Tool, hovers over a segment, holds down the Option/Alt Key, then clicks and drags the segment which causes it to bend. However, when I try, Illustrator only creates flat direction handles, not a bend. Can anyone figure out this discrepancy?

Yes, I'm using CC 2015, too. Thank you.

Edit: screen cap below

[image]

Comment: see added screen cap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out to be a simple fix: Toggle off "Constrain Path Dragging on Segment Reshape" in Preferences > Selection and Anchor Display. Honestly I don't know why that option is there. Had me stumped after hours of troubleshooting...but resolved now.

---

[image]

---

Correct behavior:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work, so I'm not sure what you are doing wrong.

All I can say is make sure it's a vector shape, either one you created with the pen or one created using one of the shape tools.

Hover over the segment, hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> (or <kbd>Option</kbd> on Mac), then the cursor turns into a little curve icon, click and drag to move it.

[image: Animation of bending a line segment]